# Why port is open when checked as root but closed for a regular user after establishing a VPN connection on Debian 11?

Tags: debian, vpn, port, openconnect

On Debian 11, I establish a VPN connection as root using openconnect. After the connection is established, I have access to a network where the IP address is 1.2.3.4.5 with an open port 1433.

Question: Why is it that when I check if port 1433 is open as root, it's okay, but for a regular user, it's closed?

**UPDATE**

I discovered that this problem concerns also public ip (no vpn). So I try:

`# iptables-save -c` results:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Oct  7 14:09:37 2023
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct  7 14:09:37 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Oct  7 14:09:37 2023
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct  7 14:09:37 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Oct  7 14:09:37 2023
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:ALLOWIN - [0:0]
:ALLOWOUT - [0:0]
:CC_ALLOW - [0:0]
:DENYIN - [0:0]
:DENYOUT - [0:0]
:INVALID - [0:0]
:INVDROP - [0:0]
:LOCALINPUT - [0:0]
:LOCALOUTPUT - [0:0]
:LOGDROPIN - [0:0]
:LOGDROPOUT - [0:0]
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 5.4.3.2/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 5.4.3.2/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 5.4.3.2/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
[117:13111] -A INPUT -s 5.4.3.2/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
[102851:9376323] -A INPUT ! -i lo -j LOCALINPUT
[461:287747] -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
[58485:5498226] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -j INVALID
[961:31240] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
[7:244] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOGDROPIN
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -j ACCEPT
[56282:5377328] -A INPUT ! -i lo -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 35000:35999 -j ACCEPT
[1:40] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
[305:18148] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
[102:5728] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
[1:44] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[77:4512] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
[2:100] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
[1052:60552] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
[5:300] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
[3:148] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
[3:164] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
[1:40] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 1583 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 7187 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
[187:14015] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 1583 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 7187 -j ACCEPT
[517:26778] -A INPUT ! -i lo -j LOGDROPIN
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -d 5.4.3.2/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[117:9540] -A OUTPUT -d 5.4.3.2/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -d 5.4.3.2/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -d 5.4.3.2/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
[100039:214161895] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -j LOCALOUTPUT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[2:88] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
[224:31289] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
[461:287747] -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
[86726:208142700] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -j INVALID
[967:31751] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p icmp -j ACCEPT
[86632:208125231] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
[3:180] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT
[2:120] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 1583 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 7187 -j ACCEPT
[12:720] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 11335 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT
[1:76] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 1583 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 7187 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -j LOGDROPOUT
[0:0] -A ALLOWIN -m set --match-set chain_ALLOW src -j ACCEPT
[65:5476] -A ALLOWOUT ! -o lo -p udp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -j ACCEPT
[9782:2268027] -A ALLOWOUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 0 -j ACCEPT
[2299:3707002] -A ALLOWOUT -m set --match-set chain_ALLOW dst -j ACCEPT
[42165:3763102] -A CC_ALLOW -m set --match-set cc_pl src -j ACCEPT
[1025:62110] -A DENYIN -m set --match-set chain_DENY src -j DROP
[26:3252] -A DENYOUT -m set --match-set chain_DENY dst -j LOGDROPOUT
[229:15410] -A INVALID -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j INVDROP
[0:0] -A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j INVDROP
[0:0] -A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j INVDROP
[0:0] -A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j INVDROP
[0:0] -A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j INVDROP
[0:0] -A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j INVDROP
[0:0] -A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j INVDROP
[0:0] -A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j INVDROP
[0:0] -A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j INVDROP
[0:0] -A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j INVDROP
[229:15410] -A INVDROP -j DROP
[102851:9376323] -A LOCALINPUT ! -i lo -j CC_ALLOW
[60686:5613221] -A LOCALINPUT ! -i lo -j ALLOWIN
[60686:5613221] -A LOCALINPUT ! -i lo -j DENYIN
[100039:214161895] -A LOCALOUTPUT ! -o lo -j ALLOWOUT
[87893:208181390] -A LOCALOUTPUT ! -o lo -j DENYOUT
[46:1944] -A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 23 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j DROP
[1:44] -A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 111 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 111 -j DROP
[2:88] -A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 113 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 113 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 135:139 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 135:139 -j DROP
[112:5804] -A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 445 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 500 -j DROP
[1:364] -A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 513 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 513 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 520 -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 520 -j DROP
[332:14124] -A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* "
[22:3846] -A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* "
[7:244] -A LOGDROPIN -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_IN Blocked* "
[362:18778] -A LOGDROPIN -j DROP
[0:0] -A LOGDROPOUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid
[0:0] -A LOGDROPOUT -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid
[0:0] -A LOGDROPOUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid
[26:3252] -A LOGDROPOUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct  7 14:09:37 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Oct  7 14:09:37 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Oct  7 14:09:37 2023
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy-save to see them
```

Comment: How do you check?

Comment: Recall that if you are checking from inside a `sudo` or `su` shell, when you exit that shell all the programs you were running in that shell are terminated. How do you establish the VPN, and (as vidarlo asked) how do you check it, both as root and as a user?

Comment: after login as debian user `sudo -s`, then `# openconnect  -b -u username --passwd-on-stdin vpnhost.com` after successful connection, I try `# telnet 1.2.3.4.5 1433` and port is open. Then I back to debian user `exit` as a debian user `$ telnet 1.2.3.4.5 1433` and port is closed `(Connection refused)`. but if a I `$ ping 1.2.3.4.5` , ip is alive, because I see `$ ps auxf` that openconnect handle vpn connection.

Comment: UPDATE, i discover that this issue happen even with public IP (without VPN)
i try:  `debian@server:~$ telnet 5.5.5.5 3306` (where ip is public and port is open) and I get : `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused` but if I try: `debian@server:~$ telnet 5.5.5.5 22` it's ok connected.
then I get sudo: `debian@server:~$ sudo -s`  next I try `root@server:/home/debian# telnet 5.5.5.5 3306` it's ok connected. I tried disable CSF firewall and repeat it , but still same

Comment: Looks like firewall rules (or routing rules for the same effect).  You should provide them: `iptables-save -c`, if adequate `nft list ruleset` and (if more than the 3 standard rules) `ip rule`.

Comment: `# iptables-save -c | grep "3306"
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
[10:600] -A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
` and when I try `debian@server:~$ telnet 5.5.5.5 3306` i see in logs: `server kernel: [16223055.368523] Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* IN= OUT=eno3 SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=5.5.5.5 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=23676 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40152 DPT=3306 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 UID=1000 GID=1000`
strange.if I try as root its ok, logs are clear. I wonder Does AppArmor can block it ?

Comment: You can't abbreviate the ruleset (no `| grep`), all of it is needed. Then you can't put this in comment, [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1145244/edit) your question instead, as should be done each time you add any piece of information.

Comment: sure, I've done.

Comment: `root` gets always allowed by the rules with the match extension `-m owner`. Other users are allowed according to an ipset. If you didn't know about it that means it's created by your CSF firewall. I don't know about CSF so can't help further than pinpointing it's about the firewall.

Comment: but if I stop CSF (DirectAdmin plugin), it doesn't effect of result and  still same problem exist